# On the relative densities of liquids

Tags: mishna, brit-milah, grapes-wine, maseches-shabbos, oil

The *Mishna*, *Shabas* chapter 19, describes beating wine with oil (to make a healing ointment for a circumcision) as something that can be done a day in advance and therefore may not be done on *Shabas*. But if they're beaten together a day in advance, they'll separate!

Comment: Maybe they would add an emulsifier?

Comment: Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: @N.T. yes, with vinegar and oil. I assume the same would apply to wine.

Comment: @JoelK maybe. Or maybe once they're beaten together there's no prohibition on doing it again? Or maybe something else? I'm open to any reasoned or sourced answer.